# Consecutive caption numbers without chngcntr?

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, chngcntr

As many before me I need consecutive caption numbers for figures and tables instead of chapter-based numbers like `Figure 1.2`. I use `scrreprt` and the `caption`-package for my document.  I also need roman table numbers and achieved it by changing the caption label format like this:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{table}{#1~#2}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=table}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
```

Since they start again with `Table I` for every chapter looking very oddly in the list of tables I tried the `chngcntr`-package. It solved the numbers of figures nicely but it overrides the roman numbers. What can I do?

Comment: thx, your speed is awesome. :) I chose the second alternative because I tried different places for the chngcntr-package before I posted the question without any change in result. And now it works great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two alternatives. The first possibility is

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
```

that I consider clearer. The second is

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\counterwithout*{table}{chapter}
```

which is slightly more efficient (maybe some nanoseconds faster).

The difference is that the *-version of `\counterwithout` doesn't change the definition of `\thetable`, while the plain `\counterwithout` applies the default definition with `\arabic`.

Answer (score 9):

Since you load the `caption` package anyway you could load it with either `within=none` (to get `figure` and `table` numbering consecutive) or `tablewithin=none` (to get `table` numbering consecutive only), e.g.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[within=none]{caption}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{table}
\caption{A}
\end{table}
\chapter{B}
\begin{table}
\caption{B}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This way you need no extra package and don't need to fiddle around with `chngcntr`-`hyperref` load order.

Comment: that works, too. thanks. with that many possibilities it looks like I didn't try to solve it by myself.. I really did but I didn't find the within-option. ;)